# Is it safe to kill the /usr/libexec processes?

Tags: process, cpu-usage

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and the laptop fans are not happy. I am just running 1 firefox window with YouTube in 1 tab, and a couple static pages in the others. No other applications are running. Specs are Dell Inspiron 7501 8 core i5 intel processor, 16GB RAM.
Running `ps aux` gives the following
[image]

I understand that /usr/libexec processes are not intended to be executed by a user, but all of the above are processes that are run as my user.

Any help would be appreciated in understanding what these processes are and if I can kill them.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/` is a *directory* - at least on an Ubuntu desktop system it contains a number of programs that might legitimately be running (in particular, related to `gvfs`) - I suggest you look at the ps output in a wider terminal so you can see the complete executable name(s) before doing anything drastic

Comment: I don't think anything is problematic about the except of ps output you show. Verify what actually is making your system heat up. Ps isn't the right tool - powertop, htop or just top might be.